An user friendly client to search into an elastic index
I have few Elastic indexes I'm currently querying through Kibana (with the Dev Console).
A developer writing elastic REST requests can work with that, but not an end user. It's also difficult for demonstrations.
What client interface would you recommend me, to allow a user to search into an Elastic index, a more convenient way?
